# BeautifulSoup's find method returning None instead of a link

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Thanks for looking into my issue here, I am trying to get the next page link from an old Reddit blog page
but somehow find method is returning me **None** object, the code :

```
 def crawl(self):
        curr_page_url = self.start_url
        curr_page = requests.get(curr_page_url)
        bs = BeautifulSoup(curr_page.text,'lxml')
        # all_links = GetAllLinks(self.start_url)
        nxtlink = bs.find('a',attrs={'rel':'nofollow next'})['href']
        print(nxtlink)
```

and the HTML page link is [Old Reddit page link](https://old.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/) on this page I'm trying to get the next pages' link
is in a span tag this one :

```
<span class="next-button">
    <a href="https://old.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/?count=25&amp;after=t3_j54ae2" rel="nofollow 
    next">next ›
    </a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to add headers to your request, otherwise the server thinks you're a bot, and it's right.

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en;q=0.5",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0",
}

response = requests.get("https://old.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/", headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser").find('a', attrs={'rel': 'nofollow next'})['href']
print(soup)
```

Output:

```
https://old.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/?count=25&after=t3_j5ezm8
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , I almost gave up after being frustrated for an hour. It worked like magic :)